# Plant UML in Visual Studio Code // Config file

Tags: visual-studio-code, plantuml

I'm using Plant UML in VS-Code to generate diagrams: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml

I want to edit the global default extension setting:

- Set input folder for the .puml files and ...
- the output folder for the generated .png files

**Question**: I can't find the config file with the *Export Settings* for PlantUML in VS Code. Where could I find it, or how shall it be set up correctly to work with the IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a directory .vscode in the root directory of your project and put a file called 'settings.json' with these settings

```
{
    "plantuml.commandArgs": [],
    "plantuml.diagramsRoot": "../docs/diagrams/src",
    "plantuml.exportOutDir": "../docs/diagrams/out"

}
```

See:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml
Go to the section called "Include Files Search Logic"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured that out when using GitHub-Code spaces, they're doing it by default.

Answer (score 2):

On vscode

1. Go to File --> Preferences --> Settings
2. Search for plantuml and you will be presented by screen below
3. Change export format
4. Set output folder, default is out
5. uncheck the box if you don't want subfolder created, check if you want subfolder
6. Test

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following  the solution made by: @andygozindy in this link, I realized that the configuration should be:

```json
{
    "plantuml.commandArgs": [],
    "plantuml.diagramsRoot": "./docs/diagrams/src",
    "plantuml.exportOutDir": "./docs/diagrams/out"

}
```

It means that is not necessary to point to other route, vscode understands where the root is instead the settings are not located at root position.

The structure of the file is the following:

Folder structure.

```bash
 RootProjectFolder
   |--.vscode
   |  |--settings.json
   |--docs
   |  |--src
   |  |  |--diagrams
   |  |  |  |--test.plantuml
   |  |  |--out
   |  |  |  |--test.svg
```